# How to use single component as page and MatDialog in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to use the single component as page and open as component MatDialog
If call from MatDialog need two way data binding
If its open as page no need to bind data

Call from component
    ```var modal = this._dialog.open(SingleComponent, {
      data: { create: true }
    });'''

SingleComponent

````
```@Component({
  selector: 'single',
  templateUrl: './single.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single.scss'],
  providers: [{
     provide: MatDialogRef,
     useValue: {close: (dialogResult: any) => { }}
  },{ provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }]
````

})
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef, 
        @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) ```

This open in both as page and modal box, but cant bind data between component and single component, and cant close from code
    `this.dialogRef.close();` not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are gettingg static injection error in console for the code you have written, you can add below lines to fix that error

In `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
   { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
   { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: [] }
  ]
```

Comment: Yes Working!,I tried this too, but i added this in single component, that's why its not working, Thank you

Comment: you mean to say that, you are trying to open single component as modal from singe component?

Comment: no, I need to open single component in modal and also as page,
    providers: [
   { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
   { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: [] }
  ]
I added this code in single component that is why its not working, After added in app.module.ts its worked

Comment: if it is the case, the above stackblitz should be fine right. what else is missing in that?

Comment: Stackblitz link is dead

Comment: Waw it's as if stackblitz based answer are a bad idea ! I'll use this thread as argument in the future when my code-less responses are denied

Answer (score 0):

declare  `dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SingleComponent>;`

```
 this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SingleComponent, { data: { create: true } });

 this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.dialogRef = null;
    });
```

in `single.component.ts` add this

`import {  MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';`

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
```

you can use value in single component in
 `data`.

Comment: I already Added, It working only when load single component from matdialoge, its not working if its load as page